# Asset Pipeline in production not loading certain assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

When I push my app to heroku certain assets are not loading and I cannot figure out why.  One of the things that I noticed is that the stylesheets that are not loading are being loaded with the path:

```
stylesheets/stylesheet.css
```

instead of

```
assets/stylesheet.css
```

In my css folder I have an .scss file in there, and that seems to be loading just fine but the others are not loading.

This is a rails 4 app.

I've played around with my settings and even installed the following gems:
"rails_12factor"
"rails_serve_static_assets"
"rails_stdout_logging"

My application.rb is as follows:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'


Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module myApp

  class Application < Rails::Application  
  end

end`
```

Production.rb is a bit longer, but for the settings related to assets I have:

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.version = 1.0
```

Does anybody have any suggestions on where to begin in order to diagnose this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the steps on the Heroku documentation about precompiling assets? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline